# Django TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse remainder

Tags: django, django-templates

I am a Django beginner and building a blog using [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srHZoj3ASmk) youtube tutorial. The lines of code below adds a list of clickable tags at the end of the blog body.

```
<div class="tags">
    {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <a href="blog/tag{{tag}}" >{{tag}}</a>
        {%  if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {{% endfor %}}
</div>
```

However, I am getting this error at the second line:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /blog/
Could not parse the remainder: '% endfor %' from '% endfor %'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doubling brackets here `{{% endfor %}}` it need to be single:

```
{% endfor %}
```